# hadoop map-reduce: how to deploy non-jar files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I was wondering how I can deploy a non-jar file when I submit my jars for a map-reduce job using `hadoop jar ..args..`.

For hadoop streaming there is the `--file` option to send files and for spark we have `--files` but I cannot find such an option in the docs.

Is it possible to ship non-jar files with my jar when submitting a hadoop map-reduce job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Applications can specify a comma separated list of paths which would be present in the current working directory of the task using the option -files](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage)

> The -libjars option allows applications to add jars to
>   the classpaths of the maps and reduces. The option -archives allows
>   them to pass comma separated list of archives as arguments. These
>   archives are unarchived and a link with name of the archive is created
>   in the current working directory of tasks. More details about the
>   command line options are available at Commands Guide.
>
> Running wordcount example with -libjars, -files and -archives:  hadoop
>   jar hadoop-examples.jar wordcount -files cachefile.txt -libjars
>   mylib.jar -archives myarchive.zip input output Here, myarchive.zip
>   will be placed and unzipped into a directory by the name
>   "myarchive.zip".
>
> Users can specify a different symbolic name for files and archives
>   passed through -files and -archives option, using #.
>
> For example, hadoop jar hadoop-examples.jar wordcount -files
>   dir1/dict.txt#dict1,dir2/dict.txt#dict2 -archives mytar.tgz#tgzdir
>   input output Here, the files dir1/dict.txt and dir2/dict.txt can be
>   accessed by tasks using the symbolic names dict1 and dict2
>   respectively. The archive mytar.tgz will be placed and unarchived into
>   a directory by the name "tgzdir".

Comment: I have found someone mentioning using this as well: `-cacheFile file.txt`.  Do you know if this does the same thing as `--files file.txt`.

Comment: `cacheFile` - distributes application-specific, large, read-only files efficiently. "The files/archives can be distributed by setting the property mapred.cache.{files|archives}.  In Streaming, the files can be distributed through command line option -cacheFile/-cacheArchive." - see more info here - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache